# Play! not shutting down H2 correctly

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, h2

I'm using Play to write a webapp which is deployed in Tomcat.  Because the app won't be processing very much data I'm using the default H2 database with Hibernate.  When I want to deploy a new version of the app, I shut down tomcat, wipe the old webapp and WAR, add my new WAR, and start back up.

This worked until a few days ago, when I added the database component.  Now, I am often unable to redeploy the app.  When I delete the old directory, it is automatically regenerated with this structure:

```
$ ls -laR myapp/
myapp/:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 WEB-INF

myapp/WEB-INF:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 application

myapp/WEB-INF/application:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 db

myapp/WEB-INF/application/db:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 h2

myapp/WEB-INF/application/db/h2:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  100 Aug 24 17:20 play.lock.db
```

The same happens when the WAR unzips.

I recently noticed a message whiz by in the catalina.out log complaining about my app not shutting down a process called something like "H2 File Lock Watchdog".  Based on a brief search of the H2 docs, I think that process is what's interfering with my app.

**EDIT**

Here's the complaining line in the log file:

`SEVERE: The web application [/myapp] appears to have started a thread named [H2 File Lock Watchdog /var/lib/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/application/db/h2/play.lock.db] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.`

So, how do I kill this process?  I can't restart the machine because it's not mine, and I can't find the watchdog with `top` or `ps`.  I'd prefer a way for Play to shut it down automagically, but I'm not above building it into my deployment script.

Thanks a million if you've read this far!

Comment: Another point worth mentioning is that the database process evidently dies eventually.  I'm not sure how long it takes, but it's on the scale of hours.  Waiting it out is only kind of a solution, but better than nothing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I shut down tomcat

Are you sure you have shut down tomcat completely? Because the H2 database is sill running. If you shut down the tomcat process, the database is also stopped (because H2 is running within the tomcat process). Except if you run the database in a different process.

Or did you just shut down the web application *within* tomcat? If that is the case, then at least one database connection was not closed, so that the database keeps running (and creates this .lock.db file).

Now, I don't know the play framework, and can't say how to ensure all database connections are closed.

One way to force the database to close is to run the SQL statement `SHUTDOWN`.

> I can't find the watchdog with top or ps

`top` and `ps` only display *processes*. The H2 watchdog is a *thread* within a java process. To see the thread, use:

```
jps -l (to get the list of Java processes)
jstack -l <pid> (to get a full thread dump)
```

Comment: I'm shutting down the server with `sh bin/shutdown.sh` as usual.  Is there anything else I should be doing?  The Play! framework tends to handle things like this automatically, so I don't know how to pass a `SHUTDOWN` statement.  I'll try killing the java process manually on Monday, and hopefully not step on anyone's toes.